Plotting ReLU and its derivative at once
I am trying to plot ReLU and it's derivative at once on my Colaboratory using matplotlib and numpy.
As the following link to my ipynb file,
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1oerk_AlfAYbvRct40MdkcsetZKyCbE_3?usp=sharing,
it works fine when I plot those two respectively on each cell. But when I try to plot these two together on one cell the graph of derivative crashs(cell 6) just like graph of 'y = 0'.
Could you please tell me what I've done wrong and what should I do to get correct graph?

So what is the problem exactly? 6 cell looks fine. The max value of the derivative is one, but the max value of ReLU in your plot is 100. That's why the derivative looks small.

@DanilKononyhin I totally forgot to check the difference of scale of y-axis from the plot result of cell 6 and cell 5.  Thank you.
